# How to recover a GSCRIPT file of a Google Apps Script Published removed from recycle bin in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a google app script published as an WebApp and it is working correctly. What happens is that accidentally the GSCRIPT file containing the source code was removed from Google Drive and also from the recycle bin.

Is there any way to recover that source code ?

I reiterate that the application currently works correctly but if I want to make any changes I will not be able to.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If the web application is still working then you should be able to find it in https://script.google.com

Answer (score 2):

### You can't recover your file or Google Apps Script project once it's permanently deleted

As per the [Google Apps Script documentation > Script Project](https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/AKfycbwR05YHdU2mSiGdDy1oYuzESNEodyrObVu5zdhlfSY/dev) says, there's no way to recover a permanently deleted file as well as [deleted deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#deleting_a_versioned_deployment).

You will be able to see the project execution logs. However if the WebApp is still working despite its deletion it probably means that the project is not permanently deleted (trash directory) and you can access via `https://script.google.com/a/DOMAIN/macros/s/ID/exec` URL. Otherwise this is not a normal behaviour and you should report this in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui)