# How to recover apps scripts if they were deleted?

Tags: google-apps-script

My apps script was suddenly deleted and i couldn't locate any logs within the revision history. Any idea if there are ways I could recover the scripts?

Comment: Sorry, but you're probably out of luck.  [How to recover a GSCRIPT file of a Google Apps Script Published removed from recycle bin in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687745/how-to-recover-a-gscript-file-of-a-google-apps-script-published-removed-from-rec)

Comment: Check with google support

Comment: Use git next time :)

Comment: Please add more details... Is you script a bounded script or a stand-alone script? Also, show what  you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You can back up you code easily with Apps Script API.  You can save each script as a simple ascii file or you can save entire projects as JSON files.  It's really nice for backups because it doesn't create any new projects which is a real nuisance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I backup my scripts:

```
function saveScriptBackupsDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('backupscripts1'), 'Script Files Backup Dialog');
}

function scriptFilesBackup(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  var scriptId = obj.script.trim();
  var folderId = obj.folder.trim();
  var saveJson = obj.saveJson;
  var saveFiles = obj.saveFiles;
  var all = true;
  var fA = [];
  if (obj.selected.length > 0) {
    all = false;
    fA = String(obj.selected).split(',').map(n => n.trim());
  }
  if (scriptId && folderId) {
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base + scriptId + "/content";
    const url2 = base + scriptId;
    const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    const data1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
    const files = data1.files;
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options);
    const data2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
    let dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    let subFolderName = Utilities.formatString('%s-%s', data2.title, dts);
    let subFolder = folder.createFolder(subFolderName)
    console.log(all);
    if (saveFiles) {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (file.source && file.name) {
          let ext = (file.type == "HTML") ? ".html" : ".gs";
          if (!all) {
            if (fA.indexOf(file.name) > -1) {
              subFolder.createFile(file.name + ext, file.source, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
            }
          } else {
            subFolder.createFile(file.name + ext, file.source, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
          }
        }
      });
    }
    if (saveJson) {
      subFolder.createFile(subFolderName + '_JSON', res1, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
    }
  }
  return { "message": "Process Complete" };
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>input{margin:2px 5px 2px 0;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="scr" name="script" size="60" placeholder="Enter Apps Script Id" />
      <br /><input type="text" id="fldr" name="folder" size="60" placeholder="Enter Backup Folder Id" />
      <br /><input type="text" id="sltd" name="selected" size="60" placeholder ="Enter Desired Files separated by commas or nothing if you want all files." />
      <br /><input type="checkbox" id="files" name="saveFiles"/><label for="files">Save Files</label>
      <br /><input type="checkbox" id="json" name="saveJson" checked /><label for="json">Save JSON</label>
      <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="backupFiles(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function backupFiles(obj) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .scriptFilesBackup(obj);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```