# I lost Google Apps Script code because I left an old tab open

Tags: google-apps-script

So I was working on a Google Apps Script project for days at work. I continued working on it at home a little. Then I closed the tab on the browser. It just so happens that another tab of the project from the start of the week was still open. So I look at that tab, and yes, it has the old version of the code. I close it. And now it turns out, that I only have the old version of the code. A week of work, gone in a few seconds, just because I forgot to close an old tab.

I looked up solutions online, and to no avail. They mentioned something about using deployments, which really doesn't solve my issue, because I didn't know about deployments to save that original code in the first place. Plus, why do I have to make deployments manually? Why doesn't it autosave a version the way we assume it saves when we press the save button? Also, I could have sworn I never pressed the save button on the old tab. What I did was such an easy mistake to make and lose hours of work, for anybody. There was another solution mentioning the legacy editor, but that's now outdated, because it was decommissioned. Why would they get rid of the legacy editor when the new editor does not have version history, and it can cost people a ton of productivity!? I've also tried using the method mentioned in this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list, but it didn't return anything on the JSON object. This is unacceptable... I just want my code back. :( Is there any other solution?

Comment: What is a tab?...

Comment: I mean like a browser tab.

Comment: Yeah I personally like backing up all of my scripts into ascii files as well as saving the a copy of the API file as an  ascii file as well.  I do it often and often grab functions from if by displaying them on a spreadsheet.

Comment: You could work on your own computer by using typescript.

Comment: I wish I could provide a solution but it's probably to late unless google support might have a backup.  If you'd  like an alternative that - [Backs up Scripts to ascii files] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929627/7215091)

Comment: do you not see it in project history (left menu)? I can see all my file revisions there.